# C# MongoDB Take 5 records from every n group

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

Hello there dear fellow developers,

I'm having trouble with MongoDB C# driver and looking for help.

I am trying to group records by the machineCode column and take 5 record from every column. And also trying to sort all the records descending by the insertDate.

So far i've tried couple threads from SO but failed in all tries.

```
var list = d3TestCollection
    .AsQueryable<D3TestData>()
    .OrderByDescending(q => q.InsertDate)
    .GroupBy(f => f.machinecode)
    .Select(f => new D3MachineListResult {
        MachineCode = f.Key,
        Values = f.Select(q => new D3KeyValueMap { Key = q.Key, Value = q.Value })
                  .Take(5)
                  .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

This code throws Method Not Supported error because of Take(5).

Thank you all.

Example collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a607be339f7c44c0d43b70"),
    "key" : "KEY1",
    "machinecode" : "3DTEST1",
    "value" : false,
    "insertDate" : ISODate("2021-05-20T06:54:54.941Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a607be339f7c44c0d43b70"),
    "key" : "KEY1",
    "machinecode" : "3DTEST2",
    "value" : false,
    "insertDate" : ISODate("2021-05-20T06:54:54.941Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a607be339f7c44c0d43b70"),
    "key" : "KEY2",
    "machinecode" : "3DTEST3",
    "value" : false,
    "insertDate" : ISODate("2021-05-20T06:54:54.941Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a607be339f7c44c0d43b70"),
    "key" : "KEY2",
    "machinecode" : "3DTEST4",
    "value" : false,
    "insertDate" : ISODate("2021-05-20T06:54:54.941Z")
}
```

Comment: Try to accumulate the documents inside the `GroupBy` stage

Answer (score 1):

You have to use aggregate and then group with project.
If you need to slice internal array, you have to use `Take` in projection, not in grouping.

```
var list = d3TestCollection //IMongoCollection<D3TestData>
        .Aggregate() //IAggregateFluent<D3TestData>
        .SortByDescending(field: x => x.InsertDate)
        .Group(
                id: x => x.machinecode,
                group: x => new D3MachineListResult
                {
                    MachineCode = x.Key,
                    Values = x
                        .Select(z => new D3KeyValueMap
                        {
                            Key = z.Key,
                            Value = z.Value
                        })
                }
            )
        .Project(
            projection: x => new D3MachineListResult
            {
                MachineCode = x.Key,
                Values = x
                    .Select(z => new D3KeyValueMap
                    {
                        Key = z.Key,
                        Value = z.Value
                    })
                    .Take(5)
                
            })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

the aggregation you need is the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        $sort: { insertDate: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$machinecode",
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            MachineCode: "$_id",
            Values: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $slice: ["$docs", 5] },
                    as: "x",
                    in: {
                        key: "$$x.key",
                        value: "$$x.value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

which cannot be done using the limited LINQ ability of the mongo driver, at least not in a strongly-typed manner.